# Magento 1.7.0.2 Get Order Info

Tags: php, oop, magento, object

I have created an observer module that will send an email whenever a certain product is bought and paid for. In order to populate that email, I need to retrieve the Shipping Address, Billing Address, and Customer Name for a given order. Thus far my Observer.php looks like this:

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model_Observer {
    public function notifyOwnerEvent($observer) {

        $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();

        // derivative data
        $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order
        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        $i = 0;
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $skus[$i] = $item->getSku();
            $i++;
        }
        $needle = 'train-01';

        if( in_array( $needle, $skus ) ) {

            ob_start();
            var_dump($skus);
            $skuDump = ob_get_clean();
            $filedump = '$skuDump: ' . $skuDump . "\n" . '------------------------------' . "\n";

            $shipAddr = $order->getBillingAddress();
            ob_start();
            var_dump($shipAddr);
            $shipAddrDump = ob_get_clean();
            $filedump .= '$shipAddrDump: ' . $shipAddrDump . "\n" . '------------------------------' . "\n";

            $billAddr = $invoice->getShippingAddress();
            ob_start();
            var_dump($billAddr);
            $billAddrDump = ob_get_clean();
            $filedump .= '$billAddrDump: ' . $billAddrDump . "\n" . '------------------------------' . "\n";

            $custName = $order->getCustomerName();
            ob_start();
            var_dump($custName);
            $custNameDump = ob_get_clean();
            $filedump .= '$custNamedump: ' . $custNameDump;

            file_put_contents('observer_log.txt', $filedump);

            $email = array(
                'to' => 'daniel@danielclarke.ca',
                'subject' => 'Confirmed Purchase',
                'message' => "
                    <html>
                        <body>
                            ". $custName ." has ordered and paid for the following products.
                            <table>
                                <th>
                                    <td>
                                        Items Ordered
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Shipping Address
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Billing Address
                                    </td>
                                </th>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        ". $skuDump ."
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        ". $shipAddr ."
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        ". $billAddr ."
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </html>",
                'headers' => 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" . 'From: Ashop.in Store'
            ); 

            //mail($email['to'], $email['subject'], $email['message'], $email['headers']);
        }

        return $this;  // always return $this.
    }
```

I have commented out the line to actually send the email preferring instead to simply output to a file as it's faster and easier given the large amount of information in the objects involved. I thought that `$shipAddr = $order->getBillingAddress();` `$billAddr = $invoice->getShippingAddress();` and `$custName = $order->getCustomerName();` would be all I need but they return large objects rather than the simple strings I need.

How do I get the Addresses and Name output into simple strings that I can insert into an email?

Thank you in advance.

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> $order->getBillingAddress()->format('html')

Also it would be better if you using the magento transactional email, take a look @ [magento sending custom emails](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-sending-custom-emails)

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you very much. the only thing I need to do now is get the customer email address. I had expected that to be part of the address, I guess I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email address like this:

```
'Email:' . print_r($order->getCustomerEmail(), true)
```